# Linear Operators, Testing for Linearity

Tags: linear-algebra

quick question

If I have an operator $L$ acting on functions $x\mapsto y(x)$ via $$Ly:=  y''' + x^2\,y\ ,$$ how would I test for linearity?

Comment: Hi Patrick, what is L acting here, what are $y$ and $x$? Are they both given?

Comment: quick question: do you know what "linearity" means? The answer would follow from the definition.

Comment: My guess is that your operator takes as input a smooth function $y$ and returns a new smooth function $y''' + x^2$.  Is that right?

Comment: ((d^3)/(dx^3) +x^2)y = sin(pi*x) is the equation I was given. I found the operator to be ((d^3)/(dx^3) +x^2). I am struggling  on determining whether this operator is linear. Apologies for the vague first question @ZackNi

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I was guessing something like that.

Comment: I think the "linear operator" is not linear because there is a $x^2$ in it. You can easily find some counter example to testify it.

Comment: This is not what I initially understood, and the operator you have now described is certainly linear as an operator on smooth functions of $x$.  $L(ay_1 + y_2) = (\frac{d^3}{dx^3} + x^2)(ay_1 +y_2) = ay_1''' + y_2''' + ax^2y_1 + x^2y_2 = (\frac{d^3}{dx^3} + x^2)(ay_1) + (\frac{d^3}{dx^3} + x^2)y_2 = aL(y_1) + L(y_2)$

Comment: @Callus yeah I was confused by x^2 I think now I get it.

Comment: Agreed, this is not my field, so maybe this is a common abuse of notation, but I think it's a bad one if it is.  $L = y''' + x^2$ looks to me like $L$ takes $y$ to $y''' + x^2$, but the operator OP intended takes $y$ to $y''' + x^2\cdot y$.

Answer (score 1):

As $L$ is defined for functions $y$ (of $x$) to check linearity  (i) you have
to take a function $y$ that is itself sum of two other functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ (of $x$) and check $L(y_1+y_2) = L(y_1) + L(y_2)$ and (ii) take the function $a.y$ (for a scalar $a$) and check $ L(ay) = a L(y)$. This is reasobaly straightforward for the given definition of $L$.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, check if the operator commutes with a linear combination.

$$\mathcal L(a\,u+b\,v)=a\,\mathcal L(u)+b\,\mathcal L(v).$$

---

Here linearity is immediate, as the derivative operators are known to be linear.

Comment: do we require that $a \neq b$? could you just use $a$ both times?

Comment: No, we do not require $a\ne b$, but we can not enforce $a=b$.